# reliabilty of 'isConnected' field in dom node

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

`domNode.isConnected` is a flag which is available in chrome. It shows whether domNode is part of the document. 
Is it cross browser compatible?
If not is there any efficient alternative for this for other browsers? 
Please provide link for any available documentation.

Comment: This sounds a little like an X/Y problem. Could you describe why you need to know whether an element is already part of the DOM, as there may be a better way to achieve what you need.

Comment: There are various ways to know if a node is part of the dom. But this I found most efficient as it requires no traversal. I just want know more about this and I cant find any thing about it anywhere.

Comment: Brief but docs here - https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-node-isconnected

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is not supported, but very easy to polyfill.

```js
(function (supported){
  if (supported) return;
  Object.defineProperty(window.Node.prototype, 'isConnected', {get})
  function get() {
    return document.contains(this);
  }
})('isConnected' in window.Node.prototype);
```

Comment: fyi: This does not work for IE10, because `document.contains` does not exist: https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/780874/node-contains-is-incorrect

Comment: ti does not exist for *nodes*, but exists for *elements*

Comment: For IE you could use document.body.contains.

Comment: FYI this polyfill is incomplete if you're working with elements inside a shadow root - those elements won't register as being contained by the document because they're in an isolated subtree.

Comment: Internet Explorer doesn't support `document.contains`. Use `document.documentElement.contains` instead.

Comment: as Skeggse mentioned is a poor polyfill since it fails for elements which are connected but are inside a shadowRoot

Comment: In addition to @stealthwang's concern, this solution is also less performant than my solution using `compareDocumentPosition()`

Answer (score 2):

A quick test shows Firefox doesn't support this property. So the answer is no.

```js
var input = document.getElementById('input');
alert(input.isConnected);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hu08awn0/

Comment: Firefox 53 added support for isConnected so this answer only applies to Firefox 52 or older

Answer (score 2):

This is a full [`node.isConnected` polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/isConnected#Polyfill) that I wrote for IE & EdgeHTML:

```
if (!('isConnected' in Node.prototype)) {
  Object.defineProperty(Node.prototype, 'isConnected', {
    get() {
      return (
        !this.ownerDocument ||
        !(
          this.ownerDocument.compareDocumentPosition(this) &
          this.DOCUMENT_POSITION_DISCONNECTED
        )
      );
    },
  });
}
```